# How to set up multiple flash .swf animations simultaneously in delphi form?

Tags: flash, delphi, forms, animation

ShockwaveFlashObjects_TLB works fine, but I can't see any way in which I can play multiple .swf at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an swf container for multiple swfs and load it into your app